# How to echo error message in browser, XAMPP and PHP 8.2.0

Tags: php, error-handling, xampp

I uninstalled existing XAMPP in Mac OS and installed the latest XAMPP with PHP 8.2.0 (not the VM version). Now an error-handling routine that worked before no longer works:

```
<?php
  $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "false_db_name");

  if (!$conn) {
    echo "Error: Unable to connect to database. ";
    echo "Debugging errno: " . mysqli_connect_errno();
    echo " Debugging error: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    exit;
  }
?>
```

In previous versions of XAMPP/PHP, using "false_db_name" instead of an existing database name would result in the error text being written directly into the browser window, which is handy for beginners unused to error logs.

Now, however, I just get a generic HTTP ERROR 500 and no error messages.

I would like to go back to the old way, but I don't know how to bypass the HTTP ERROR 500 page. Here's a screenshot of what it used to do:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/vYn4a.jpg

.

Answer (score -1):

do know if this has been resolve but here is here is an useful link to help you out
[solution](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N1qF41imRks)

you just have to edit the php.ini file to enable display_error to On

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).